# Problem with spacing in syntactic trees using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, syntax

I am trying to get a tree like this using the tikz package

[image]

and the syntax for this, according to a manual, is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mytree]
\node (top) {DP}
child {node {D\\the}}
child {node {NP}
child {node {Adj\\brown}}
child {node {NP\\dog}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, just copying and pasting this code gives me

[image]

It seems that `\\` is not recognized. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add text options to your nodes, for instance, `align=center`.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center] %[mytree]
    \node (top) {DP}
    child {node {D\\the}}
    child {node {NP}
    child {node {Adj\\brown}}
    child {node {NP\\dog}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```